# python regex combine patterns with AND and group

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use regex to match something meets the following conditions:

1. do not contain a "//" string
2. contain Chinese characters
3. pick up those Chinese characters

I read line by line from a file:

```
f = open("test.js", 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
for line in lines:
    matches = regex.findall(line)
    if matches:
        print(matches)
```

First I tried to match Chinese characters using following pattern:

```
re.compile(r"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+")
```

it works and give me the output:

```
['下载失成功']
['下载失败']
['绑定监听']
['该功能暂未开放']
```

Then I tried to exclude the "//"  with the following pattern and combine it to the above pattern:

```
re.compile(r"^(?=^(?:(?!//).)*$)(?=.*[\u4e00-\u9fff]+).*$")
```

it gives me the output:

```
['           showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");']
```

which is almost right but what I want is only the Chinese characters part.

I tried to add "()" but just can not pick up the part that I want.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: `^(?!.*//)(?=.*[\u4e00-\u9fff]+)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need so complex regex for just negating `//` in your input and capturing the Chinese characters that appear in sequence together. For discarding the lines containing `//` just this `(?!.*//)` negative look ahead is enough and for capturing the Chinese text, you can capture with this regex `[^\u4e00-\u9fff]*([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)` and your overall regex becomes this,

```
^(?!.*//)[^\u4e00-\u9fff]*([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)
```

Where you can extract Chinese characters from first grouping pattern.

**Explanation of above regex:**

- `^` - Start of string
- `(?!.*//)` - Negative look ahead that will discard the match if `//` is present in the line anywhere ahead
- `[^\u4e00-\u9fff]*` - Optionally matches zero or more non-Chinese characters
- `([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)` - Captures Chinese characters one or more and puts then in first grouping pattern.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kKjTbR/1)**

**Edit: Here are sample codes showing how to capture text from group1**

```
import re

s = '           showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");'

m = re.search(r'^(?!.*//)[^\u4e00-\u9fff]*([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)',s)
if (m):
 print(m.group(1))
```

Prints,

```
该功能暂未开放
```

[Online Python Demo](https://rextester.com/XOJ51658)

**Edit: For extracting multiple occurrence of Chinese characters as mentioned in comment**

As you want to extract multiple occurrence of Chinese characters, you can check if the string does not contain `//` and then use `findall` to extract all the Chinese text. Here is a sample code demonstrating same,

```
import re

arr = ['showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");','//showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");','showToastByText("未开放");','showToastByText("该功能暂xxxxxx未开放");']

for s in arr:
 if (re.match(r'\/\/', s)):
  print(s, ' --> contains // hence not finding')
 else:
  print(s, ' --> ', re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+',s))
```

Prints,

```
showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");  -->  ['该功能暂未开放']
//showToastByText("该功能暂未开放");  --> contains // hence not finding
showToastByText("未开放");  -->  ['未开放']
showToastByText("该功能暂xxxxxx未开放");  -->  ['该功能暂', '未开放']
```

[Online Python demo](https://rextester.com/LSARS91027)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but only partially answers the question - it appears that the problem OP has is knowing how to select a specific matching group, once the correct regex is used. Can you extend your answer?

Comment: @Grismar: Oh ok. Let me add a sample code for capturing the grouping pattern. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Thanks for you answer :)

Comment: @supersuraccoon: Glad I could help. Please feel free in case you want any further clarification or any kind of help.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi I found a slight issue now if the text to search is `showToastByText("该功能暂xxxxxx未开放")` then then output is `该功能暂` instead of `该功能暂` and `未开放` that I really want ...

Comment: @supersuraccoon: For capturing multiple sequence of Chinese characters present mutliple times in non-continuous manner, the strategy will have to be changed. You will need to use `findall` and since you also want the string should not contain `//` so first you should check that string doesn't contain `//` separately.

Comment: @supersuraccoon: I've updated my post to give you the solution like you want. This should work for you and let me know for anything else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a positive lookahead to get the chinese characters (as it will not match anything). So we can rewrite that part to make a lazy match for `.*` until it finds the desired characters.

As such, using:

`^(?=^(?:(?!//).)*$).*?([\u4e00-\u9fff]+).*$`

Your first capture group will be the chinese characters